# Convex relaxation for the complement of Lorentz cone

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Is it possible to obtain a convex relaxation for 
$$
\{ (x,t): t \le \|x\|_2\} \in \mathbb{R}^{d+1}
$$
where $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and $\|x\|_2$ is the usual Euclidean norm, 
by moving to higher dimensions and projecting back (the so-called lifting)?

Comment: The image of a convex set under projection (and any linear map) is convex, so the answer appears to be negative.  I may have misunderstood the question.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. What I mean is something which approximates this set in some sense.

Comment: ... I am even open to nonlinear maps as projections if the result is useful. (The question is more or less open-ended.) In deriving convex relaxations/approximations to many problems of interest, this set or its sister $\{ (X,t) : t I \preceq X\}$ comes up.

Comment: One can map the half-plane $\{t\le 0\}$ onto $\{t\le \|x\|\}$ by a reasonably explicit nonlinear map. Would this help?

Comment: It might. Not quite sure without seeing it. Could you give more details if it is not too much effort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cone $\{ (x,t): t \le \|x\|_2\} $ cannot be the image of a convex set under a linear map. But it can be realized as the image of the halfspace $\{ (x,t): t \le 0 \} $  set under the following  nonlinear map: $F(t,x) = (t+\|x\|_2,x)$. The map is a bijection, the inverse being  $F^{-1}(t,x) = (t-\|x\|_2,x)$. It is a kind of *shear deformation*.